# Max amount of moves it would take knight to move to any give space

Tags: python, recursion, combinatorics

Hello I am a grade 11 student taking a grade 12 computer class coding in python. I am trying to figure out how many moves it would take for a knight to capture the king from any given space on a 8 by 8 grid. I have already written the code to solve the problem using recursion, but now I am stuck with the problem of what the maximum moves it would take to get from any given square because it runs slower the move cases I have to check. I have found similar problems on stack overflow but nothing that answers my question. If you would like to see the code please just ask. Thank you for any responses it is greatly appreciated. This is the problem i am trying to solve:

4. In the game of chess, there is a piece called a knight. The knight moves in an L-path, by moving two spaces in one direction and then one space in a 90O direction.
   An 8x8 chess board can be defined as a 2-D list where the top left corner is (1,1), and the bottom right corner is (8,8).

In this problem, you are given a text file, knight.txt, that contains six lines of information. The first line contains the position of the king on the chessboard. The next five lines contains the position of a knight on the chess board. Your task is to calculate home many moves it takes the knight to capture the king.
For example, if the text file knight.txt contains the following:
(6,3)
(4,4)
(6,6)
(4,1)
(2,5)
(5,7)

the output of your program could look as follows:

Knight Moves

It takes 1 moves for the knight at (4,4) to capture the king at (6,3).

It takes 3 moves for the knight at (6,6) to capture the king at (6,3).

It takes 4 moves for the knight at (4,1) to capture the king at (6,3).

It takes 2 moves for the knight at (2,5) to capture the king at (6,3).

It takes 3 moves for the knight at (5,7) to capture the king at (6,3).

The code i have written so far:

```
print "Knight Moves"
print "------------\n"
#This function will try to find the shortest route to the king usi
def findDaKing(knightX,knightY,moveNum):
    #Checks if the king and knight are on the same spot
    if knightX <0 or knightX >7 or knightY <0 or knightY >7:
        pass
    elif chessBoard[knightY][knightX] == 1:
        return moveNum
    #finds if it has moved 10 times so i doesnt hit max resuresion depth or waste time
    if moveNum == 6:

        return -1
    #moves the knight
    else:
        #uses resursion so because i don't know how else to do it :)
        #finds the shorts route for each path and compares them

        shortestRoute = findDaKing(knightX+2,knightY-1,moveNum+1)
        temp =findDaKing(knightX+2,knightY+1,moveNum+1)
        #checks if it found a route
        if temp == -1:
            pass
        elif temp==1 or shortestRoute ==1:
            return 1
        #checks if the first one found a path and if not temp must be a shorter route or if its bigger than temp
        elif shortestRoute == -1 or shortestRoute> temp:
            shortestRoute  = temp
        temp =findDaKing(knightX+1,knightY-2,moveNum+1)
        #checks if it found a route
        if temp == -1:
            pass
        elif temp == 1:
            return 1
        #checks if the first one found a path and if not temp must be a shorter route or if its bigger than temp
        elif shortestRoute == -1 or shortestRoute> temp:
            shortestRoute  = temp
        temp =findDaKing(knightX+1,knightY+2,moveNum+1)
        #checks if it found a route
        if temp == -1:
            pass
        elif temp == 1:
            return 1
        #checks if the first one found a path and if not temp must be a shorter route or if its bigger than temp
        elif shortestRoute == -1 or shortestRoute> temp:
            shortestRoute  = temp
        temp =findDaKing(knightX-1,knightY+2,moveNum+1)
        #checks if it found a route
        if temp == -1:
            pass
        elif temp == 1:
            return 1
        #checks if the first one found a path and if not temp must be a shorter route or if its bigger than temp
        elif shortestRoute == -1 or shortestRoute> temp:
            shortestRoute  = temp
        temp =findDaKing(knightX-2,knightY+1,moveNum+1)
        #checks if it found a route
        if temp == -1:
            pass
        elif temp == 1:
            return 1
        #checks if the first one found a path and if not temp must be a shorter route or if its bigger than temp
        elif shortestRoute == -1 or shortestRoute> temp:
            shortestRoute  = temp
        temp =findDaKing(knightX-2,knightY-1,moveNum+1)
        #checks if it found a route
        if temp == -1:
            pass
        elif temp == 1:
            return 1
        #checks if the first one found a path and if not temp must be a shorter route or if its bigger than temp
        elif shortestRoute == -1 or shortestRoute> temp:
            shortestRoute  = temp
        temp =findDaKing(knightX-1,knightY-2,moveNum+1)
        #checks if it found a route
        if temp == -1:
            pass
        elif temp == 1:
            return 1
        #checks if the first one found a path and if not temp must be a shorter route or if its bigger than temp
        elif shortestRoute == -1 or shortestRoute> temp:
            shortestRoute  = temp
        #returns the shortest Route
        return shortestRoute
#checks if the format is right
def checkFormat(string):
    #checks if its the right len
    if len(string) !=5:
        return True
    #checks if it has the right syntax
    elif string[0] != "(" and string[4] != ")" and string[2] == ",":
        return True
    #checks if they are numbers
    elif not(string[1].isdigit()) and not(string[3].isdigit()):
        return True
    #else returns false so I know that it is the right format.
    return False
#This will be used to check if the text file failed to open
textFileFail = False
#trys to read from the text file
try:
    chessTextFile = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in open("knight.txt")]
except:
    #Prints that the text file failed and set the program no to run
    print "The text file failed to open."
    textFileFail = True
#This will be the 2-d list that holds the board
chessBoard = [  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                ]
if textFileFail == False:
    #runs through all the lines in the text file
    for line in range(0,len(chessTextFile),1):
        #checks the format of the chess point
        Format = checkFormat(chessTextFile[line])
        #if the format error is true it failed to read it
        if Format == True:
            #print that it didnt work and what line the error was on
            print "Sorry the format for line",line+1,"was incorrect."
            #If it happened on the first line the reset of the program wont work so it just breaks else it continues in hopes of some working
            if line == 0:
                break
            else:
                continue
        #if its the first one I know its the kings x and y
        if line == 0:
            #sets the x and y based on the string in the list
            chessBoard[int(chessTextFile[line][3])][int(chessTextFile[line][1])] = 1
        #Else I know its a starting point
        else:
            #prints how many moves it will take
            print "It takes",findDaKing(int(chessTextFile[line][1]),int(chessTextFile[line][3]),0),"moves for the knight at",chessTextFile[line],"to capture the king at",chessTextFile[0]+"."
```

I hope the comments help. Sorry if its a little messy or hard to read.
Ps. thank you for all the responses this is my first time asking a question.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code you've written already.

Comment: You should try [PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) for programming challenges. SO is really not the place for such questions

Comment: Surely you want the minimum number of moves,  the maximum is infinite if the knight can re-visit squares.

Comment: It seems like homework though. Does that fit within the codegolf rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt but this isn't well optimized:

```
king = [4,1]
knight = [[6,3]]
c = 0
while king not in knight:
    moves = []
    for i in range(len(knight)):
        for j in [-1,1]:
            for k in [-2,2]:
                for l in [0,1]:
                    if knight[i][l] + j>0 and knight[i][l] +j < 9 and knight[i][abs(l-1)] + k > 0 and knight[i][abs(l-1)] + k < 9:
                        moves.append([0,0])
                        moves[len(moves)-1][l] = knight[i][l] + j
                        moves[len(moves)-1][abs(l-1)] = knight[i][abs(l-1)] + k
    c += 1
    knight = list(moves)
print(c)
```

Comment: I would like to say thank you for answering my question and I think this answers my question and works for what I am doing.